# Why didn't Helen close her eyes and keep them closed?

Tags: plot-explanation, incredibles-2

In *Incredibles 2*, after it was revealed that the pizza delivery guy was controlled by goggles and Evelyn reveals her plans to Helen, the latter being tied up in a chair, why didn't Helen close her eyes and keep them closed? That would have kept her from being re-hypnotized.

Answer (score 2):

The hypnosis happens fairly quickly while Helen and Evelyn are talking (about a second in movie time) and with Evelyn being a small distance away with a small remote to trigger the hypnosis, so it's possible Helen didn't have the time to react properly (especially as she was being slowed / heavily affected by the ice-cold area around).

[image: distance between Helen and Elastigirl]

[image: remote in Evelyn's hand]

Of course, it's a movie for kids, so instead of a long drawn-out scene with Helen keeping her eyes closed, suffering some torture to make her open her eyes OR Evelyn just waiting until her eyes opened (eg after Helen slept and woke up), it just happened straight away.